# File Upload of size more than 50 MB to Chatter Feeds through Visual Force

Tags: visualforce

I am trying to implement upload files to Custom object's record through Visualforce and Apex.

I have enabled FeedItem for the object. I am using Blob as file type but Visualforce is not allowing me to attach file more than 10 MB.

While I am using `chatter:feed entityId="{!Document.Id}"` component in VF page, its file option allow me to upload more than 50 mb file.

What I have to do, so that Visual force should provide similar functionality as Chatter File and allow me to upload at least 50 MB file .

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this via Visualforce - the limit is clearly documented at:

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_inputFile.htm

> Note: The maximum file size that can be uploaded via Visualforce is 10
>   MB.

You should be able to upload larger files via the REST API. The forcetk should help you in this situation too.  For an example that uploads a photo via REST, check out Pat Patterson's blog post:

https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2013/11/uploading-photos-to-chatter-files-with-html5.html

Answer (score 0):

With the use of chatter Rest API I am able to upload upto 500 mb. Below is the snippet of code I used.

```
XHR.open('POST', '/services/data/v34.0/chatter/feed-elements'); //add headers 
XHR.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data; boundary=' + boundary);
XHR.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + __sfdcSessionId); 
XHR.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
```